# How to merge two columns of same data type from table-1 to single column in Table-2?

Tags: sql, syntax, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, merging-data

What is the SQL to accomplish the below?

**Table-1**

```
id      |name             |aka-name  
1       |Victor           |vicky  
2       |Nicholas         |nicki  
3       |Jefferson        |jeff
```

Expected output:

**Table -2**

```
id     |name  
1      |Victor  
2      |Nicholas  
3      |Jefferson  
4      |Jeff  
5      |Nicki  
6      |Vicki
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select row_number() over(order by name) as id, name
from (
select name as name
from mytable
union all
select aka_name as name
from mytable) A
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fb6c7f6e22c65c1a74d3f4a4edeb3da)

And if you need the aka_name column to result in a first upper case letter then you can use this:

```
select row_number() over(order by name) as id, name
from (
select name as name
from mytable
union all
select UPPER(LEFT(aka_name,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(aka_name,2,LEN(aka_name))) as name
from mytable) A
```

Comment: It worked perfect and appreciate your inputs.